# Change object in array's key name

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, json

```
arr = [
    {"id":"1"},
    {"id":"2"}
];
```

For some reason I want to change the `"id"` to `"uid"`. I am stuck here

```
arr.forEach(function(i){

});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```js
arr = [{
    "id": "1"
  },
  {
    "id": "2"
  }
];
arr.forEach(function(i) {
  i.uid = i.id;
  delete i.id;
});
console.log(arr);
```

This will modify `arr`. If you want a copy of `arr` that has the changed structure, follow Mritunjay's answer.

Answer (score 1):

Just do like bellow:

```js
arr = [{
    "id": "1"
  },
  {
    "id": "2"
  }
];
arr = arr.map(function(obj) {
  return {
    "uid": obj.id
  }
});

console.log(arr);
```

Comment: This returns a new object in place of the old one, if OP decides to add more elements to the object, this won't work as properly without back and forth editing

Answer (score 0):

Here you go:

```
arr.map(function (a) {
    a.uid=a.id;delete a.id;
    return a;
});
```

This just goes through the **array**, renames it, and returns the value.

Snippet:

```js
var arr = [{
  "id": "1"
}, {
  "id": "2"
}];

arr = arr.map(function(a) {
  a['uid'] = a['id'];
  delete a['id'];
  return a;
});

console.log(arr);
```

---

You mentiond **`forEach`** so here's an answer with it.

```
arr.forEach(function (a) {
    a.uid=a.id;delete a.id;
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
arr = [{
    "id": "1"
  },
  {
    "id": "2"
  }
];
arr = arr.map(function(item, index) {
  // forget about the index, e.g. running from 0 to arr.length - 1
  return {
    uid: item.id
  };
});
console.log(arr);
```

Comment: nah.. lots of duplicate with others.. but fun anyways.

Comment: this is the exact same as Mritunjay's answer